# My program just stopped printing in the outputFile after I add some changes

Tags: c, loops, hash, iterator, hashtable

I created an iterator on my hashTables to help on encapsulating the code.However, on some functions, it just didn't work.For example, on "query3" after I apllied the changes, it worked just fine.

```
void query3(bool formatFlag, char *args, int commandLineNum,  ReservationHashTable* reservationTable) {
    char outputFileName[1024];
    sprintf(outputFileName, "Resultados/command%d_output.txt", commandLineNum);
    FILE* outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");
    if (!outputFile) {
        perror("Erro ao abrir o arquivo de saída");
        return;
    }
    
    if (args == NULL || reservationTable == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    char *hotelId = trim(args);

    double totalRating = 0.0;
    int numRatings = 0;

    ReservationIterator *iterador = initReservationIterator(reservationTable);
    if (iterador == NULL) {
        return;
    }   

    Reservation *reserva;

    while ((reserva = getNextReservation(iterador)) != NULL) {
        const char* reservationHotelId = getReservationHotelId(reserva);
        int reservationRate = getReservationRate(reserva);

        if (reservationHotelId != NULL && strcmp(reservationHotelId, hotelId) == 0) {
                totalRating += reservationRate;
                numRatings++;
        }
    }

    double averageRating = (numRatings > 0) ? totalRating / numRatings : 0.0;

    if (formatFlag) {
        fprintf(outputFile, "--- 1 ---\n");
        fprintf(outputFile, "rating: %.3lf\n", averageRating);
    } else {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%.3lf\n", averageRating);
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
}
```

but on "query4" it stopped working

old query4:

```
int compareReservations(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Reservation *resA = *(const Reservation **)a;
    const Reservation *resB = *(const Reservation **)b;

    int dateCompare = strcmp(getReservationDataIni(resA), getReservationDataIni(resB));
    if (dateCompare == 0) {
        // Usar strcmp para comparar os IDs corretamente
        return strcmp(getReservationId(resA), getReservationId(resB));
    }
    return -dateCompare; // Negativo para ordem decrescente
}

void query4(bool formatFlag, char *args, int commandLineNum, const ReservationHashTable *reservationHashTable) {
    
    if (args == NULL || reservationHashTable == NULL) {
        printf("Argumentos inválidos para a query4\n");
        return;
    }

    int conta = 1;
    char* hotelId = trim(args);

    int n_reservas = getReservationTableCount(reservationHashTable);
    int numFiltradas = 0;

    Reservation **reservasFiltradas = malloc(n_reservas* sizeof(Reservation*));
    if (reservasFiltradas == NULL) {
        return;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < getReservationTableSize(reservationHashTable); i++) {
        ReservationHashNode *node = getReservationTableBucket(reservationHashTable, i);
        while (node != NULL) {
            Reservation *reservation = getReservationFromNode(node);
            if (strcasecmp(getReservationHotelId(reservation), hotelId) == 0) {
                if (numFiltradas == n_reservas) {
                    n_reservas *= 2;
                    reservasFiltradas = realloc(reservasFiltradas, n_reservas * sizeof(Reservation*));
                    if (reservasFiltradas == NULL) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                reservasFiltradas[numFiltradas++] = reservation;
            }
            node = getNextReservationHashNode(node); // obter o próximo nó
        }
        
    }

    qsort(reservasFiltradas, numFiltradas, sizeof(Reservation*), compareReservations);

    char outputFileName[1024];
    sprintf(outputFileName, "Resultados/command%d_output.txt", commandLineNum);
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");
    if (!outputFile) {
        perror("Erro ao abrir o arquivo de saída");
        free(reservasFiltradas);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numFiltradas; i++) {

        Reservation *reservation = reservasFiltradas[i];
        double totalPrice = calcularPrecoTotal(getReservationPrice(reservation),
                                              getReservationTax(reservation),
                                              getReservationDataIni(reservation),
                                              getReservationDataFim(reservation));
    if (formatFlag){

        fprintf(outputFile, "--- %d ---\n", conta);
        fprintf(outputFile, "id: %s\n", getReservationId(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "begin_date: %s\n", getReservationDataIni(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "end_date: %s\n", getReservationDataFim(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "user_id: %s\n", getReservationUserId(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "rating: %d\n", getReservationRate(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "total_price: %.3lf\n", totalPrice);

        if(i<numFiltradas-1) fprintf(outputFile,"\n");

        conta++;

    }

    else {

       fprintf(outputFile, "%s;%s;%s;%s;%d;%.3lf\n",
                getReservationId(reservation),
                getReservationDataIni(reservation),
                getReservationDataFim(reservation),
                getReservationUserId(reservation),
                getReservationRate(reservation),
                totalPrice);
        }

        
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
    free(reservasFiltradas);
}
```

new query4:

```
#include "query4.h"

// Assumindo que as funções mencionadas e estruturas de dados estão definidas.

// Função auxiliar para comparar datas (e IDs como desempate)


int compareReservations(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Reservation *resA = *(const Reservation **)a;
    const Reservation *resB = *(const Reservation **)b;

    int dateCompare = strcmp(getReservationDataIni(resA), getReservationDataIni(resB));
    if (dateCompare == 0) {
        // Usar strcmp para comparar os IDs corretamente
        return strcmp(getReservationId(resA), getReservationId(resB));
    }
    return -dateCompare; // Negativo para ordem decrescente
}

void query4(bool formatFlag, char *args, int commandLineNum, ReservationHashTable *reservationHashTable) {
    
    if (args == NULL || reservationHashTable == NULL) {
        printf("Argumentos inválidos para a query4\n");
        return;
    }

    int conta = 1;
    char* hotelId = trim(args);

    int n_reservas = getReservationTableCount(reservationHashTable);
    int numFiltradas = 0;

    char outputFileName[1024];
    sprintf(outputFileName, "Resultados/command%d_output.txt", commandLineNum);
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");
    if (!outputFile) {
        perror("Erro ao abrir o arquivo de saída");
        return;
    }

    Reservation **reservasFiltradas = malloc(n_reservas* sizeof(Reservation*));
    if (reservasFiltradas == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    ReservationIterator *iterador = initReservationIterator(reservationHashTable);
    if (iterador == NULL) {
        return;
    }   

    Reservation *reserva;

    while ((reserva = getNextReservation(iterador)) != NULL) {
        if (strcasecmp(getReservationHotelId(reserva), hotelId) == 0) {
            if (numFiltradas == n_reservas) {
                n_reservas *= 2;
                reservasFiltradas = realloc(reservasFiltradas, n_reservas * sizeof(Reservation*));
                if (reservasFiltradas == NULL) {
                    return;
                }
            reservasFiltradas[numFiltradas++] = reserva;    
            }
        }
    }

    qsort(reservasFiltradas, numFiltradas, sizeof(Reservation*), compareReservations);

    for (int i = 0; i < numFiltradas; i++) {

        Reservation *reservation = reservasFiltradas[i];
        double totalPrice = calcularPrecoTotal(getReservationPrice(reservation),
                                              getReservationTax(reservation),
                                              getReservationDataIni(reservation),
                                              getReservationDataFim(reservation));

    if (formatFlag){

        fprintf(outputFile, "--- %d ---\n", conta);
        fprintf(outputFile, "id: %s\n", getReservationId(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "begin_date: %s\n", getReservationDataIni(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "end_date: %s\n", getReservationDataFim(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "user_id: %s\n", getReservationUserId(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "rating: %d\n", getReservationRate(reservation));
        fprintf(outputFile, "total_price: %.3lf\n", totalPrice);

        if(i<numFiltradas-1) fprintf(outputFile,"\n");

        conta++;

    }

    else {

       fprintf(outputFile, "%s;%s;%s;%s;%d;%.3lf\n",
                getReservationId(reservation),
                getReservationDataIni(reservation),
                getReservationDataFim(reservation),
                getReservationUserId(reservation),
                getReservationRate(reservation),
                totalPrice);
        }

        
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
    free(reservasFiltradas);
}
```

Iterator:

```
ReservationIterator *initReservationIterator(ReservationHashTable *table) {
    ReservationIterator *iterator = malloc(sizeof(ReservationIterator));
    if (iterator != NULL) {
        iterator->table = table;
        iterator->currentBucket = -1;
        iterator->currentNode = NULL;
    }
    return iterator;
}

Reservation *getNextReservation(ReservationIterator *iterator) {
    // Se o iterador já está no final, retorne NULL
    if (iterator->currentBucket >= iterator->table->size) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Avançar para o próximo nó ou bucket, se necessário
    if (iterator->currentNode == NULL || iterator->currentNode->next == NULL) {
        do {
            iterator->currentBucket++;
            if (iterator->currentBucket >= iterator->table->size) {
                return NULL; // Chegou ao final da tabela
            }
            iterator->currentNode = iterator->table->buckets[iterator->currentBucket];
        } while (iterator->currentNode == NULL);
    } else {
        iterator->currentNode = iterator->currentNode->next;
    }

    if (iterator->currentNode != NULL) {
        return iterator->currentNode->reservation;
    }

    return NULL; // Se chegar aqui, não há mais voos
}
```

some structs that might help:

```
    struct ReservationHashTable {
        ReservationHashNode **buckets;
        int size;
        int count;
    };

    struct ReservationHashNode {
        Reservation *reservation;
        struct ReservationHashNode *next;
    };

    struct ReservationIterator {
        ReservationHashTable *table;
        int currentBucket;
        ReservationHashNode *currentNode;
    };

 struct Reservation {
    char* id;
    char* user_id;
    char* hotel_id;
    char* hotel_name;
    int hotel_stars;
    int city_tax;
    char* address;
    char* begin_date;
    char* end_date;
    int price;
    char* breakfast;
    char* room_details;
    int rate;
    char* comment;
};
```

I tried to do some changes on the code but I really need this iterator to work to keep my code encapsulated.

Also, If anyone of you has another idea of something that I can use instead of the iterator but that could also keep my code encapsulated and would be willing to help me, I would be really gratefull.

Can anyone help me out please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the differences between your old and new code? How much did you add and modify between tests? If you only add or modify one or two lines at a time it becomes much easier to test, find and debug problems, and fix them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the changes were all the same basically. I changed the way that I was doing the first loop for that appears.

Comment: try a fflush() before fclose()?

Comment: @Syntactics `fclose()` automatically flushes.

Comment: Could you clarify what doesn't work? Is `numFiltradas` different in the two versions?

Comment: @Barmar no, it is the same on the two codes.
Basically, instead of directly grab the next node, I created a functin that iterates on the hashtable. 

After doing that, the resulted stopped being printed on the outputfile.

When I apllied that change to query3 it worked just fine, but the problem only happened on query4.

Comment: What if you print to stdout instead of the file?

Comment: @Barmar doesn't work aswell.

Comment: It's time to run it under a debugger so you can see what's wrong with `reservasFiltradas`

Comment: Look in detail at the changes you made between the last working version and the current failing version.  You are keeping your code in a VCS (version control system) such as Git, aren't you?  So you have a good record of what you changed?  If not, now is a good time to start because you need to be able to record and recover working versions so you can do such comparisons.

Comment: Help others to help you: post something we can compile, complete. Maybe it is too much to ask for others to cut and paste from segments of code, then add headers, then figure out where your problem could be in.

Comment: Also avoid these 20-letter+ variable names. Consider Stack Overflow in Portuguese at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ or to translate relevant comments to english

Comment: About things like `ReservationHashTable`, `ReservationHashNode` and `ReservationIterator`: understand that these should not exist at all. There is hash table, there is iterator, there is linked list. Data Structures are abstract containers of nodes. The nodes points to one data record (or contains one). If these structures use the same data you should use the same NODE. Good abstractions are essential to build models.

Comment: Data structures are about nodes, not about your data. A node is not the structure.  Or at least should not be.